# Display UserControl Based on Selection of ComboBox WinUI 3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I'm trying to migrate an existing WPF app to WinUI 3.  Unfortunately I've run into a problem where I am unable to load a UserControl based on the selection of a ComboBox as was done in WPF.

In the past, I've used a DataTemplate to connect the selected property to the desired view. I've migrated the view below with what I believe to be correct WinUI syntax using x:Bind with an instantiated ViewModel in the .xaml code behind but I cannot get the ContentControl to load any view based on a user selection.  I've tried using a DataTemplateSelector as well but I had no luck and not sure if it is necessary. Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to get the view to load when selecting the object from a ComboBox?

I will also note that both soccerFieldViewModel and baseballFieldViewModel are separate classes that inherit from a ISportsField Interface and are included in a Observable list which is bound to the ComboBox ItemsSource property.

I tried this code but literally nothing is displayed when I select something from the ComboBox. If I replace the Content of the ContentControl to a static reference to one of the views

```
<fieldViews:soccerFieldView/>
```

then it will display, but obviously it will not change based on a selection.

```
<Page x:Class="Sports.Views"
             xmlns:fieldViews="using:Sports.Views.Fields"
             xmlns:fieldViewModels="using:Sports.ViewModels.Fields">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- Assign the data context for each field view to its corresponding view model here-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="soccer" x:DataType="fieldViewModels:soccerFieldViewModel">
            <fieldViews:soccerFieldView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="baseball" x:DataType="fieldViewModels:baseballFieldViewModel">
            <fieldViews:baseballFieldView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Sports}"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedSport}"/>           
        <!-- Individual Sport Field Views-->
        <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedSport}"/>
        
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `DataTemplateSelector`:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Sports;

public class FieldViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate? SoccerFieldTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate? BaseballFieldTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate? SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return item?.ToString() switch
        {
            "Soccer" => SoccerFieldTemplate,
            "Baseball" => BaseballFieldTemplate,
            _ => base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container),
        };
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Sports.Views"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:fieldViewModels="using:Sports.FieldViewModels"
    xmlns:fieldViews="using:Sports.FieldViews"
    xmlns:local="using:Sports"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!--  Assign the data context for each field view to its corresponding view model here  -->
        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="Soccer"
            x:DataType="fieldViewModels:SoccerFieldViewModel">
            <fieldViews:SoccerFieldView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate
            x:Key="Baseball"
            x:DataType="fieldViewModels:BaseballFieldViewModel">
            <fieldViews:BaseballFieldView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:FieldViewTemplateSelector
            x:Key="FieldViewTemplateSelector"
            BaseballFieldTemplate="{StaticResource Baseball}"
            SoccerFieldTemplate="{StaticResource Soccer}" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Sports}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedSport, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <!--  Individual Sport Field Views  -->
        <ContentControl
            Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedSport, Mode=OneWay}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FieldViewTemplateSelector}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Note that `x:Bind` is `OneTime` by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#:%7E:text=%7Bx%3ABind%7D%20has,part%20of%20the%20binding.), so don't forget to set the `Mode`.

Comment: Also, I have a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPUue7mg4EE) about using DataTemplateSelector with Dictionary of DataTemplates, just if you are interested.

Comment: I got this to work by following your example and using the DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: Great! I recommend you consider using a Dictionary for the DataTemples so you can add new sports fields without modifying the DataTemplateSelector.